# Two times inherited from a generic class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, instance, generic-programming

I have two class

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour   where T : Component
{
    protected static T _instance;


    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>
{
    // Lots of Methods and Properties...
}
```

I want to create 3. class derived from GameManager for example ShooterGameManager. I can create ShooterGameManager with

```
public class ShooterGameManager : GameManager
{}
```

but Instance is still GameManager !!!, 
I tried something like to added extra class definition with generic class.

```
public class GameManager<T> : Singleton<T> where T : Component
{}
```

but this time there are 2 completely different classes available, nothing inherited from GameManager. **What should I do ???**

Comment: what do you mean _but Instance is still GameManager_?

Comment: When a GameManager object is created,  Instance type is a GameManager in the VisualStudio, but When a ShooterGameManager is created Instance type is still GameManager.  I can use like "(ShooterGameManager)Instance" but there are lots of using, Is there a way change Instance type to a ShooterGameManager

Comment: public class ShooterGameManager : GameManager
    {}

Comment: code is working, but I need change Instance type to a ShooterGameManager **in VisualStudio**, ı can use like _(ShooterGameManager)Instance_

Comment: Sorry, code from an Unity project, you need Unity to run, on me It is working without any error, I just could not figure out how to write code using with Generic classes

Comment: You seem to want to have it both ways: that (1) there is a single GameManager, and (2) that there are arbitrarily many GameManagers, one of each derived type. Those are contradictory. The fundamental problem here is that "singleton" is a poor candidate for a base type. You use a base type to share implementation details and enable polymorphism, but there are no implementation details to share amongst singletons, and no reasonable scenario for a method that takes singletons polymorphically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Create GameManager like this

```
public GameManger<T> : Singleton<T>
{}
```

then you could create GameManger

```
public GameManager : GameManager<GameManger>
{}
```

and ShooterGameManager

```
public ShooterGameManager : GameManager<ShooterGameManager>
{}
```

and repeat for the other two types you need to create

an example below proves this works

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new GameManager(); //Prints GameManager
        new ShooterGameManager(); //prints ShooterGameManager
    }


}

public class Singleton<T>
{
    private T _instance;

    public Singleton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

public class GameManager<T> : Singleton<T>
{
}

public class GameManager : GameManager<GameManager>
{
}

public class ShooterGameManager : GameManager<ShooterGameManager>
{
}
```

Comment: Wow =D that solved the problem thanks a lot @Dave, you saved me from a big headache

Comment: You should look at @Eric Lippert's answer while not directly solving the question it is directing you down a better route for the future

Answer (score 8):

> What should I do ???

You should delete the Singleton base class utterly and forget that you ever wrote such a thing.  It does nothing helpful and causes you pain, so why are you using it?

Then write:

```
abstract public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected GameManager() { whatever }
    // Lots of Methods and Properties...
}

public sealed class ShooterGameManager : GameManager
{
  private ShooterGameManager() { whatever } 
  private static ShooterGameManager instance = new ShooterGameManager();
  public static ShooterGameManager Instance { get { return instance; } }
}
```

Done.  Making the base class a singleton causes you pain and saves you from typing exactly two lines of code. Whether a derived class is a singleton or not is an implementation detail of that derived class; don't force that upon your derived class authors.

Comment: Yes, I thought a bit, this way looks easier. i will use this method. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Just as side note, this is Unity and MonoBehaviour, you cannot user constructor with those MonoBehaviour. This is a Unity restriction.